# Can r change private function into built-in function by save the private function somewhere such as python？

Tags: r

When you have written a private function and save it in the `c:\privates.R`,everytime you source it `source("c:\privates.R")` ,can i save it in somewhere and everytime i start r,input  `private(x)` to get the result ?people can do that way in python ,it is convenient .please do not to recommend using package method 'install.packages(),then library() `,it is unconvenient.

Comment: Downvote for bad literature ... and no code.

Comment: @DWin, let's hope that in a world of computer masters, we can still be hopeful for at least better vocabulary than "unconvenient", though I would also like to see better punctuation and capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking for the .Rprofile file. Details are [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html), but the basic idea is that you create a file called `.Rprofile` in your home directory, and R will source that file every time you start it.